# ID of a layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, ows

I want to publish my map by using ArcGIS Runtime API for .NET. The map is stored in GeoServer. Esri has a function called WmtsLayer() which takes two parameters: first is the URL of the map that is taken from GeoServer and the second is layerID.

I do not know how to learn the layer ID in GeoServer.
Where the ID of a layer is stored?

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers of any layer in an OGC web service are discoverable through a GetCapabilities request, for example for a WMS service, the request would be like:

```
http://an-ogc-service/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
```